# Restricting access to certain controllers to Azure APIM only

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

we have a pretty big and old codebase written in ASPNET core protected using OIDC. There are tens of controllers. Let's say there are 50 controllers. Of these, 45 gets called from our frontend. And 5 are APIs that facilitates integration workflows with our partners.
I intend to move these partner facing APIs behind Azure APIM to be able to manage them using policies and be able to monetise them in future.
While those APIS are accessible from APIM, they are also accessible directly from partner side. Which means I cannot really force our partners to go via the APIM route always.

Any pointers?

While I can check for the presence of some identifier that will only get populated by APIM, I don't want to do that. This still does not protect etc endpoint from being called from partner's side.

Comment: Please let me know what you have tried from your end? Kindly share the policy which you have created if any?

Comment: Hey @IkhtesamAfrin, the policy I intend to use is basically quota and rate limiting. But shouldn't that come later? The intent right now is to prevent direct access of the API from outside and allow only from APIM.

Comment: you want a policy which prevent direct access to the API from outside?

Comment: I don't think I can do that. 90% of the APIs get consumed by a frontend. I'm not sure if I can do that on a per controller/action basis.

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirement here, I mean what you are trying to achieve? It will be easier for me to help you, if I will understand your exact requirement

Comment: Yes, You can prevent direct access to an API by the external users when it is hosted on APIM

Answer (score 1):

The question you need to answer is if you're ok having endpoints exposed, but not callable directly, which is fine in most cases, or you want to actually make endpoints not available for direct calls. For the latter only VNET approach would work, but it could get complicated. For the former you do have some options:

1. Shared secret. As you propose yourself, have APIM set a secret header/query and validate that in your backend. Partners will still be able to call directly, but you could make your API always return 404/401 if secret is not provided.
2. If you backend is in Azure, you could use Managed Identity instead of secret.
3. For extra security, you could use certificate authentication with backend. Have APIM add client certificate to backend request and backend validate that certificate.
4. Somewhat less advised option is to validate caller's IP address on your backend. APIM does have static IP address, so depending on your service's layout you may be able to make your backend respond only if call came from APIM.
5. VNET. You'd have to put your backend into VNET along side with APIM. And then expose partner facing APIs via some other gateway, and non partner facing ones via APIM.